# update via CLI with error!

Tags: craft3

I'm trying an update on the CLI and get the following error.

If I do it again afterwards I get told that everything is up to date.
If I want to install a plugin then I still get the message that I should update to the current version.

Who can tell me what I am doing wrong or where the mistake lies?

```
$ php-7.2-cli -d allow_url_fopen=1 craft update all
Fetching available updates ... done
Performing one update:

    - craft 3.1.25 => 3.1.28

Backup the database? (yes|no) [yes]:yes
Backing up the database ... done
Performing update with Composer ... done
Applying new migrations ... error: The command "'/home/lichtebs/CraftCMS-ALL/craft' 'migrate/all' '--no-content'" failed.

Exit Code: 255(Unknown error)

Working directory: /home/lichtebs/CraftCMS-ALL

Output:
================
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unexpected character in input:  '' (ASCII=92) state=1 in <b>/home/lichtebs/CraftCMS-ALL/craft</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in <b>/home/lichtebs/CraftCMS-ALL/craft</b> on line <b>16</b><br />

Restore the database backup? (yes|no) [yes]:yes
Restoring the database backup ... done
Revert the Composer changes? (yes|no) [yes]:yes
Reverting Composer changes ... error: The command "'/home/lichtebs/CraftCMS-ALL/craft' 'update/composer-install'" failed.

Exit Code: 255(Unknown error)

Working directory: /home/lichtebs/CraftCMS-ALL

Output:
================
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in <b>/home/lichtebs/CraftCMS-ALL/craft</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in <b>/home/lichtebs/CraftCMS-ALL/craft</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to have `php-7.2-cli -d allow_url_fopen=1` in front of your `craft` commands. When you run `craft update all`, Craft then tries to run migrations (`craft migrate/all`) but without your `php-7.2-cli...` declaration it seems to fails.

If you have access to composer, you could try to update 'manually' instead of running `craft update`.

1. run `composer update`
2. then `php-7.2-cli -d allow_url_fopen=1 craft migrate/all`

Answer (score 1):

ah ok, I did not think that it will be redirected.
Then I realize that these configs can not get through. Then I'll go and reconfigure the CLI that I do not have to pass the parameters. Because then it would have to work "normally"